Drag and Drop Mat-tree and keep showing dragged element inside starting list
Every time I drag an element outside its list, said element is hidden/removed until I drop it in the same list or in another one.
In conclusion I want the list to not change its layout while I'm dragging one of its elements.
Something like this except a Mat-Tree

